# PowerShell keeps on adding periods to my renaming

Tags: powershell, rename

I have a problem with the codes that I am using.

```
cd "C:\Users\eulla\Documents\GAB\ZZZZ"
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "Insurance Marketing Solutions PPLLC","IMS-PPLLC" }
Get-ChildItem -Path "*Pain*" -File | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace '(?<=\bPain\b).*(?= -)'}
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "PAIN","Pain" }
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "SCAR","Scar" }
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "DERMATITIS","Dermatitis" }
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "ANTI-FUNGAL","Anti-Fungal" }
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "METABOLIC","Metabolic " }
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "MUSCLE RELAXANT","Muscle Relaxant" }
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "ALLERGY","Allergy" }
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "Psoriasis","Dermatitis" }
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "PSORIASIS","Dermatitis" }
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "_"," " }
Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '(.*?)- \w+(.*)', '${1}- Dr.${2}' }
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "  "," " }
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "Dr. Wilson Hall","Dr. Hall" }
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "Dr. Foster Chapman","Dr. Chapman" }
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "Dr. Scott Hill","Dr. M Hill" }
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "Dr. Hill","Dr. S Hill" }
```

This is the code that I am currently using. So the problem is renaming should look like this:

From this:

- RX Insurance Marketing Solutions PPLLC - Benjamin  Frizner - Anthony Tolton - PA - Pain, Scar, Dermatitis & Muscle Relaxant - Lidocaine_Tetracaine 7%_7% Cream
- RX Insurance Marketing Solutions PPLLC - Benjamin  Frizner - Anthony Tolton - PA - Muscle Relaxant - Chlorzoxazone 250 mg Tablet
- RX Insurance Marketing Solutions PPLLC - Benjamin  Frizner - Anthony Tolton - PA - Psoriasis - Fluovix
- RX Insurance Marketing Solutions PPLLC - Benjamin  Frizner - Anthony Tolton - PA - SCAR - Silivex Pad

To this:

- RX IMS-PPLLC - Dr. Frizner - Anthony Tolton - PA - Pain - Lidocaine Tetracaine 7% 7% Cream
- RX IMS-PPLLC - Dr. Frizner - Anthony Tolton - PA - Muscle Relaxant - Chlorzoxazone 250 mg Tablet
- RX IMS-PPLLC - Dr. Frizner - Anthony Tolton - PA - Dermatitis - Fluovix
- RX IMS-PPLLC - Dr. Frizner - Anthony Tolton - PA - Scar - Silivex Pad

So the problem is after running the script/code in PowerShell it works fine then some of the files gets renamed like this:

- RX IMS-PPLLC - Dr............................................................................................................................ Frizner - Anthony Tolton - PA - Pain - Lidocaine Tetracaine 7% 7% Cream
- RX IMS-PPLLC - Dr......................................................................................................................................................  Frizner - Anthony Tolton - PA - Scar - Silivex Pad

Others get renamed normally as they should be.

This is the error that I am getting in PowerShell:

```
Rename-Item : Could not find a part of the path.
At line:14 char:17
+ ... childitem | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '(.*?)- \w+(.*)', ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Users\eulla\...Silivex Pad.pdf:String) [Rename-Item], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RenameItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

I don't know what seems to be the problem with the codes that I am using.

UPDATE!!
This is the code that has a problem
`Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '(.*?)- \w+(.*)', '${1}- Dr.${2}' }`

Comment: what is the input string that produces the unwanted output or errors?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Updated the question

Comment: you don't seem to have the original text of the two lines that are damaged. where is the `Mokhashi` original? where is the ` Koller` original?

Comment: Are these real people or fake names??

Comment: @Lee_Dailey sorry pasted the wrong info. Anyway it does not matter since this code `Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '(.*?)- \w+(.*)', '${1}- Dr.${2}' }` should replace the first names of the doctor (Benjamin) to **"Dr."** without changing also the patient's name as per the example above its **Anthony Tolton** just in case the first name of the doctor is the same with the patient's. In my folder I have a total of 63 doctors with different names.

Comment: @Theo these are fake names. I wont post the real ones. But the the renaming is exactly the same. Just changed the names of the doctor and the patient

Comment: Glad to hear that

Comment: You are constantly getting a list of filenames and renaming them. Why not get the list of filenames once, for each file do all the replacements in a variable and do the rename once per file?

Comment: @Theo I actually made one for each

Example: `Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "Benjamin Frizner","Dr. Frizner" }`

Maybe there is another way that I could do this with just one code. Because there are new doctors everytime

Comment: @GabrielBalenton - `Theo` has apparently hit on your problem - you are re-re-re-reading the file names and something is getting out of sequence. calls to the file system are not guaranteed to always happen in the same order, so i suspect you are seeing out-of-order replacements triggering errors. load your file names ONCE, iterate thru the collection, **_chain the replace calls_**, and then do the rename. ///// you can call `-replace` multiple times on the same item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead or using `Get-ChildItem` and `Rename-Item` over and over again (one reason for getting you into trouble), get the list of files once and rename them once using a new calculated name.

Something like this:

```
# create a Hashtable with all uppercase strings you want to replace
$upper2lower = @{
    'PAIN'            = 'Pain'
    'SCAR'            = 'Scar'
    'DERMATITIS'      = 'Dermatitis'
    'ANTI-FUNGAL'     = 'Anti-Fungal'
    'METABOLIC'       = 'Metabolic'
    'MUSCLE RELAXANT' = 'Muscle Relaxant'
    'ALLERGY'         = 'Allergy'
    'PSORIASIS'       = 'Dermatitis'  # shouldn't this be 'Psoriasis' ??
}

Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\eulla\Documents\GAB\ZZZZ" -Recurse -File | ForEach-Object {
    $newName = $_.Name -replace "Insurance Marketing Solutions PPLLC","IMS-PPLLC"
    $newName = $newName -replace '(?<=\bPain\b).*(?= -)'
    # convert the uppercase stuff using the $upper2lower Hashtable
    foreach ($name in $upper2lower.Keys) {
        $newName = $newName -replace $name, $upper2lower[$name]
    }
    $newName = $newName -replace '_', ' ' -replace '(.*?)- \w+(.*)', '${1}- Dr.${2}' -replace '\s+', ' '

    # now do the names. because these have dots you need to escape for regex
    $newName = $newName -replace [regex]::Escape('Dr. Wilson Hall'),'Dr. Hall'
    $newName = $newName -replace [regex]::Escape('Dr. Foster Chapman'),'Dr. Chapman'
    $newName = $newName -replace [regex]::Escape('Dr. Scott Hill'),'Dr. M Hill'
    $newName = $newName -replace [regex]::Escape('Dr. Hill'),'Dr. S Hill'
    $newName = $newName -replace [regex]::Escape('Dr. Benjamin Frizner'), 'Dr. Frizner'

    # finally rename the file
    $_ | Rename-Item -NewName $newName -Force
}
```

P.S.1 The second problem stems from the fact that `-replace` uses Regular Expression and therefore you need to escape any character that has special meaning in regex like the dot (`.`)

P.S.2 Like the `$upper2lower` hashtable, you could also create a `$doctors` hashtable and put all names, followed by the replacement names in there. Then do a foreach loop:

```
foreach ($doctor in $doctors.Keys) {
    $newName = $newName -replace [regex]::Escape($doctor), $doctors[$name]
}
```

This helps keeping the code more readable IMO when you have a lot of doctors around..